# Jackhammer away third basement floor?

Tags: basement

I am putting French drains in my basement and I did one side already. When getting the one side done, the contractors found that there was a second floor poured on top of the old (he said people do that to stop water from leaking in). There was about 6” of gravel, and then a layer of concrete.

The second half of the basement is about 5” higher, and the contractors believe that side has THREE layers. My question is, is it completely out of the question to jack hammer away the entire third concrete floor? Even if it takes hours and hours and hours. I am willing.  I just want opinions from others about things I may be overlooking. Thanks!!

Comment: I usually cut a line first and then its not so hard to break up but in this case the top one would need to be slightly wider than the bottom one. As far as hours and hours are they using a small or light weight Jack hammer?

Comment: You’re putting a french drain “in” your basement? I don’t understand...you mean you’re putting a french drain around the exterior perimeter walls, right?

Comment: @Ed Beal: thanks! This is helpful, jackhammer looked pretty heavy duty, but I don’t know anything about jackhammers.

Comment: @Lee Sam: Yes a drainage system around the perimeter of the basement near the outer walls, but on the inside.